# How to prove that $(X^y - X) \bmod 3 = 0$ always when $y$ is odd and $y > 1$, and $X >1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation

My question is quite simple: how to prove that $(X^y - X) \bmod 3 = 0$  when $y$ is odd and $y > 1$, and $x $ is an integer greater than $1$?

Examples:

$(2^3-2)/3=2$

$(11^3-11)/3=440$

$(7^5-7)/3=5600$

$(49^3-49)/3=39200$

$(13^7-13)/3=20916168$

Not always true for when $y=2$ (or other even numbers) examples:

$(5^2-5)/3 = 6.6666666\ldots$

$(5^4-5)/3 = 206.666666\ldots$

$(11^2-11)/3 = 36.666666\ldots$

Comment: Modulo $6$ is redundant. All that's needed is modulo $3$ and this should be straightforward.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire. Just fixed it. Thanks

Comment: Why do you have $X^y-X$ in the subject line but then $x^y-x$ in the body of the question?

Comment: Consider the cases $X=3x,3x+1,3x+2$. Modulo $3$ this reduces $X^y-X$ to $0^y+0,1^y+1,2^y+2$ respectively. The first two cases are proved immediately. For the last case note that $2^y+2\equiv(-1)^y-1\pmod3$.

Comment: Special case $\,n = 3,\,$ direction $(\Leftarrow)$ of the Theorem linked in the dupe (whose proof is very simple in that direction).

Comment: Thanks @Bill, for the closure!

Comment: Thanks @Bill Yes it answers my question

Comment: Have you notice the remainder is either $0$ or $2$ it is never $1$?  Note: we are never considering the remainder of $x^M$ without also considering the remainder of $x$.  If the remainder of $x$ is $r$ where is the remainder of $x^M$ and what is the remainder of $x^M - x$.  Also note:  $x^M-x = x(x^{M-1} - 1)$  what does that tell you.